# Is a Buffalo CB-GK10B Router the same as a WZR-HP-G300NH? Or will installing OpenWRT brick the CB-GK10B

Tags: linux, router, flash, buffalo-router

I have an old [WZR-HP-G300NH](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0028ACYEK), and I thought I ordered another one, it said `WZR-HP-G300NH` on the package, but when I opened it up and looked at the unit the back read `Model No: CB-GK10B`. 
It looks physically the same but I'm wondering if it's actually safe to install OpenWRT on it given the strange model number labeling on the box.  It's brand new, I want to use it, but I don't really care to brick it.

Answer (score 1):

Used latest stable (Attitude Adjustment Release 12.09) with the migrate directions listed for the WZR-HP-G300NH, worked great. I enabled telnet on DD-WRT though and used a local HTTP server to get the disk image. I did not have it plugged into the internet at the time.

http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/buffalo/wzr-hp-g300h#migrate.from.dd-wrt.to.openwrt

I would **NOT** use backfire to be safe.

Comment: Which firmware did you use?  There's a whole bunch of'm in there...http://downloads.openwrt.org/attitude_adjustment/12.09/ar71xx/generic/

I'm planning on flashing it from dd-wrt after downloading the file on windows and connecting with WinSCP.